# SQL Select AND OR

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written an SQL query on a work bench that has the game details 100 different British football teams playing over a season. The team name, where the team is based, the dates on which the teams play games, the status of the team, etc are the attributes. In other words, the table would have rows that might look like this :

```
Liverpool FC, Liverpool, 2013-12-25, Professional 
Arsenal FC  , London   , 2013-10-18, Professional
Swindon FC  , Swindon  , 2013-12-25, Amateur
```

Now, these are just three teams, but my table has details of 100 teams and what I need to do is to find out the dates on which two teams (say, Liverpool and Swindon) BOTH play. In the rows above, you can see that Liverpool and Swindon BOTH play on 2013-12-25. I write my SQL query like so:

```
  SELECT date
  FROM footballclubs.tableofgames
  WHERE (team = 'Liverpool') AND (team='Swindon');
```

I am expecting the date 2013-12-25 to appear on the workbench, but all I get is blank. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? When I replace the word AND with the word OR, I get a long list of dates but that is NOT what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a date where BOTH Liverpool AND Swindon have played matches, so surely the word AND is required? Please help.

Comment: basically one row cannot be both Liverpool and swindon, @trogdor provides a solution by using the table twice.

Comment: What you are selecting in your query is every row where Liverpool and Swindon both appear in the `team` column, that i swhy you fiund nothing. Joining the table with itself will help, see trogdor's answer :)

Comment: where team in ('Liverpool','Swindon') GROUP BY date HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;

Comment: its `WHERE (team='Liverpool' AND team = 'Swindon')` also if you like to get teams which play on particular date use `SELECT team FROM tableofgames WHERE date = '2013-12-25'` or you can group them by date using inner join to same table

Comment: almog.ori, oerkelens, Ali Exalter, thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to join the table with itself to find all pairs of teams playing the same day, and then add the condition for your teams:

```
SELECT date
FROM footballclubs.tableofgames a 
    JOIN footballclubs.tableofgames b ON a.date=b.date
WHERE a.team='Liverpool' AND b.team='Swindon';
```

Comment: Well, you don't *need* to, but you can!

Comment: Trogdor, much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

change your code this way:

```
SELECT g1.date
FROM footballclubs.tableofgames g1, footballclubs.tableofgames g2
WHERE (g1.team = 'Liverpool') AND (g2.team='Swindon') AND (g1.date=g2.date);
```

or more readable:

```
SELECT g1.date
FROM (SELECT date FROM footballclubs.tableofgames WHERE team='Liverpool') g1 
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT date FROM footballclubs.tableofgames WHERE team='Swindon') g2
USING (date)
```

Comment: Saaed, I tried your method and it works absolutely fine (even the less readable version!) Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2975787, Thanks, you can give my answer a positive score if the answer was usefull